# simplejson decoder for a python script

Tags: python

I am trying to parse the code with simplejson using a python script.

```
{ "name":"some",
  "products_valid_time_from":2011-08-01T14:45:00,
  "products_valid_time_to":2011-08-01T21:00:00,
  }
```

Ia m getting an error

```
simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting , delimiter: line 2 column 34 (char 52)
```

Can some one help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Dates are not part of JSON. See for example [this blog entry](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2008/01/18/dates-and-json.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Your dates need to be in quotes. It's just another string to the JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

The format is wrong.

You can follow this [json rule](http://www.json.org/)

You can save your date as string first.
Then when you retrieve that value, you can use alternative library to convert string into date.